# Determine the data type of csv and print as column in Python

Tags: python, csv, types

I have a several MB text file with random data types separated by commas:

bgh5w  ,12, 5.223,   ab4ft55, ....

There are only four types of data: integer, float, alphabets and alphanumeric. 
How to print out the data types in column form?:

bgh5w   - alphanumeric

12 - integer

5.223 - float

ab4ft55 - alphanumeric

.
.
.

Comment: What tools are to be used? In something like e.g Perl this is a one-liner, in C it is a bit of work....

Comment: Hi, I'm using Python.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not possible. CSV data must be accompanied by metadata, that is, information about the data itself.

But....
What you can do is read some part of your file (or read it wholly) and decide which datatype to use for each column using heuristics. Then do a 2nd pass reading the data and casting it to the appropriate data type (found on the 1st pass).

On the 1st pass you could keep some true/false (aka boolean) information about each column, like "hasDecimalDigit" (if in some line the characters '0' to '9' were found), "hasHexadecimalDigit" (for characters 'a' to 'f'), "hasPeriod" (for '.'), "hasMoreThanOnePeriod" (for '.' when "hasPeriod" is already true), "hasAlphaCharacter" (for characters 'a' to 'z'), and so on. After an arbitrary number of rows is read you could decide on specific pattern of your information set which datatype is applicable (for example: hasDecimalDigit & !hasHexadecimalDigit & !hasAlphaCharacter & !hasPeriod -> datatype = int, format = decimal).

Comment: what if it is given that there are only 4 types of data in the file? (int, float, alphabets, alphanumeric)

Comment: What I said before still applies. The heuristics will certainly be simpler (that is, less boolean features to test).

Comment: If you still has questions about this answer, show what you have already accomplished (edit your original post and include your source code, what you've done so far).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text file the only datatype you have is a String. My suggestion is to use a mapping file where you can lookup the column # to a datatype, at that point it should be pretty straightforward loading the data by your process. The mapping file should be delivered together wit the CSV since requires insights on the nature of the data contained in the CSV.

Comment: what if it is given that there are only 4 types of data in the file? (int, float, alphabets, alphanumeric)

Comment: When you read the column value from the file you get back a string type, then you should use the isalpha(), isdigit(), isalnum() to detect 3 of the 4 cases you have listed. Any integer can be considerated a float, it's really hard to tell unless you parse the value and you assume that if there are not decimal parts you want a int.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods As other users already said, post your code and be more specific about what is blocking you.